# How to make fontSize of text area increase by 2 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have textarea that I want to add 2 to its text font size every time a button is clicked. I wrote this code but not working.
My HTML code is

```js
function makebold() {
  alert(document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize);
  var currentfontsize = document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize;
  console.log(currentfontsize);
  var current = parseInt(currentfontsize);
  console.log(current);
  var updatedfontsize = current + 2;
  console.log(updatedfontsize);
  var newfont = updatedfontsize;
  console.log(newfont);;
  document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize = newfont;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Text</legend>
  <textarea name="input-text" id="input-text" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Decoration</legend>
  <button id="button1" onclick="makebold()">Bigger Decorations!</button><br>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="displayalert()" name="bling" id="bling" value="Bling">Bling
</fieldset>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: @Robson I want to increase the font size by 2 when the button is clicked.

Comment: By 2 what? The current size could be in px, pt, pc, in, mm, em, rem, ex, ch, vw, vh, %,... (also you are setting an invalid size at the end because you are missing the unit entirely)

Comment: by 2 points or pixels can work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this way to get the font size:

```
  var currentfontsize = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("input-text")).fontSize;
```

And update your last line

```
 document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize = newfont+'px';
```

You are not adding px to the font. Without px it won't work.

Working Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3napv795/

Answer (score 0):

```
function increaseFont(elem, inc) {
    const val = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("font-size"); // gets font-size in string format
    const currentSize = parseFloat(val); // removes 'px' 
    elem.style.fontSize = currentSize + inc + "px";  // set new size by adding increment to current font size
}
```

Usage:

```
const button = document.getElementById("button1");
button.addEventListener("click", () => increaseFont(button, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an initial font-size will solve the problem:

```
function makebold(){
    alert(document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize);
   //add initial font-size
   document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize = '10px';
    var currentfontsize = document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize;
    console.log(currentfontsize);
    var current = parseInt(currentfontsize);
    console.log(current);
    var updatedfontsize = current + 2;
    console.log(updatedfontsize);
    var newfont = updatedfontsize;
    console.log(newfont);;
    document.getElementById("input-text").style.fontSize = newfont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your code while updating to a newer syntax  ....

**JS**

```
  
  const textarea = document.getElementById("input-text");

  
  function makebold() {
    let fontUnit = "px"; // setting a unit for font size
    let increment = 2; // increase the font size by 2 px/rem/em etc ..
   // Getting current font size 
    let currentfontsize =  window.getComputedStyle(textarea).fontSize;
    
    currentfontsize = parseInt(currentfontsize);
 
   // getting final value 
    const updatedfontsize = currentfontsize + increment + fontUnit;
  
    textarea.style.fontSize = updatedfontsize;
  }
```